# Kotlin: Split string whitespace delimiters

Tags: kotlin, delimiter

In Kotlin, I need to split a line by white spaces. I tried here using what I think is a space and a tab. Also in case there are multiple delimiters, I used a `+`. I try to grab the 3rd thing in that delimited string below:

```
val lines = File(MyFilePath).readLines()

val two = lines[7].trim().split("\\\s+","\\\t+")[2]
```

Comment: any readon why you are not using a simple `str.split("\\n", "\\t")` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe try like this:

```
val list: List<String> = lines[7].trim().split("\\s+".toRegex())
val two = list[1]
```

Comment: Will that capture tabs as well?

Comment: @David Pesetsky Yes, it captures tabs - I checked.

Comment: "\\s+".toRegex() gives you the regular expression that matches one or more consecutive whitespace characters: blank, tab, newline, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can simply use this :

```
Var arr : Array<String> = yourString.split(" ").toTypedArray()
```

Inside the split method just enter a white space and it will split your string.

Comment: This will not work for tab as asked as part of the question!